# Regular expression to allow maths operators + reserved variables

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to strip out everything from a string that is not a defined maths operator or a reserved word.

```
function run($value)
{
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9\+\-\*\/\(\)\.]/', '', $value);
}


echo run('23*10 /SDF (ABC * 2) + 3 / XYZ');
```

In the above example ABC and XYZ are accepted reserved words (I've not been able to get these working in the regex) and need to be allowed. Making the expected outcome:

```
23*10/(ABC*2)+3/XYZ
```

For clarity the allowed characters are:

```
any integer "0-9"
plus "+"
minus "-"
divide "/"
multiply "*" 
open/close parenthesis "(" ")"
```

And the allowed reserved words are:

```
ABC
XYZ
```

Comment: Show `reserved words` list, please

Comment: ABC & XYZ are the only reserved words

Comment: I'm getting absolutely hammered on negatives, can anyone explain to me why this question is so badly constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will match your criteria:

```
[-+*/0-9()]+|ABC|XYZ
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bV9bZ4/1)

Just get all the matches and concatenate them together to get the desired output.

---

If you insist on using `preg_replace`, replace this with an empty string:

```
(?:ABC|XYZ)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^-+*/0-9()]
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nV7xH9/1)

But this is both more complicated and *slower* than the recommended method above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to inverse it so the output is everything that DOESN'T match the regex. See http://3v4l.org/ddMbe

Comment: @Lee use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_replace` then concat the results as I said. Your keyword requirement makes it *much* easier this way. I added the replacement method so you can see why it's better to use the first one.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. preg_match_all('/[-+*\/0-9()]+|ABC|XYZ/', $value, $matches) works perfect.